# Visual Studio Extension for Custom Memory Window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, com, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-package

My custom tool window in a Visual Studio Extension package is supposed to evaluate custom expressions during debug sessions for VS2012 and VS2013. The final goal is to build a graphical watch window. Therefore, I must fetch the value of the expression result from the debug engine.

The evaluation works fine via

```
IDebugStackFrame2 -> IDebugExpressionContext2 -> ParseText 
IDebugExpression2 -> EvaluateSync -> IDebugProperty2
```

The first problem here: On Visual Studio 2013 `ParseText()` does not correctly report errors. But the `IDebugProperty2` retrieved is valid (for valid expressions). On VS2012 I get proper errors for invalid expressions.

This is where the real problem starts. The result Property2 represents a complex custom object. In order to visualize it, a specific property from one of its *base* classes needs to get retrieved. In my current attempt, I am using `IDebugProperty2.EnumChildren()` to walk along its members up to the right place in the class hierarchy, similar as one would do in the Locals window in Visual Studio:

```
[result] -> base -> Raw -> base -> Non-public Members -> [private field] ... a.s.o.
```

This is somehow working but introduces the following problems:

### Problem 1: Get an internal member of some complex object

The members and their order received from EnumChildren() seem to depend on some factors, which are not obvious to me: 
* Does the object has a Debug Visualizer attached? (VS2013 ignores enum_DEBUGPROP_INFO_FLAGS.DEBUGPROP_INFO_VALUE_RAW in EnumChildren and gives back the beautified version + a "Raw View" node, VS2012 works as expected)
* Is a 'Non-public Members' node shown? Sometimes it is, sometimes not - dunno from what it depends on
* Setting of 'Just my code' (? I read about it in several posts but couldn't really figure out a reliable rule)
* ... there must be other dependencies ?

This turns out to be a *really* hacky way of aquiring an internal member of some complex expression result object. What could be a better way? Using IDebugProperty3 and some Debugger Visualizer tricks? Any pointer would be great.

### Problem 2: VS2012 fails to give memory bytes

Once I have the private member of the result object, I use `IDebugProperty2.GetMemoryBytes()` in order to 'serialize' its value (a plain System.Array) and transfer it to my Custom Tool Window. While this is working in VS2013, in VS2012 `IDebugProperty2.GetMemoryBytes()` always returns VS_Constants.S_FALSE. I am really out of ideas here. Since there is a Memory Window in VS2012, there ought to be some way to get this working here also? What am I missing?

The code used to query the memory API:

```
IDebugMemoryContext2 memCtx = null;
IDebugMemoryBytes2 memBytes = null;

// getting the memory context is working ok
if (tmpProperty2.GetMemoryContext(out memCtx) == VSConstants.S_OK

  // VS2012 fails here, always returns S_FALSE, memBytes remains null:
  && (tmpProperty2.GetMemoryBytes(out memBytes) == VSConstants.S_OK)) { 
  ...
```

Some more context:

```
OS: Windows 8 and 8.1 
Visual Studio: 2012 / 2013
Tool Window built with MPF (C#) in VS2013, (removed all vers. 12 references from the package before deploying to VS2012)
Debug engines: C# and Visual Basic
```

Comment: The documentation, FWIW, says that VS calls `GetMemoryBytes` on the `IDebugProgram2` and not the `IDebugProperty2` (though it uses its `IDebugMemoryContext2`) to read bytes for the memory window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161954.aspx